# Vue Component not showing - Passport Implemenation Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-passport

I am trying implement passport using Laravel 5.4 and I have followed the official documentation step by step. Everything seems to be working fine as per instructions till the point I hit **"Frontend Quickstart"**

As instructed I published the vendor using

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

This gave me the components as expected. After which I registered my components in my app.js

**app.js**

```
/**
 * Add the CSRF Token to the Laravel object. The Laravel object is being 
 * used by Axios and the reference can be seen in ./bootstrap.js
 * 
 * Requires the token be set as a meta tag as described in the documentation:
 * https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token
 */

window.Laravel = { csrfToken: document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content }

/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * The Vue components for managing the OAuth setup
 */

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

/**
 * Instantiate Vue for use 
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I installed the dependencies and build the components

```
npm install 
npm run dev
```

Placed the components in my home.blade.php (test purpose)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <passport-clients></passport-clients>
                    <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
                    <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

But nothing shows up in the view. I tried searching a lot in this topic but all the solutions seems to be pointing towards the gulp config. But Laravel 5.4 doesn't use gulp anymore it uses webmix.

I have been struggling with this for a while now, looking for the communities expert option to help be get through this.

Thanking You.

Comment: Where is the `#app` in DOM ? Also does browser console say anything ?

Comment: the #app is in my @extends('layouts.app'). I tried to render the example.vue in the same page it seems to be working..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've added `<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.min.js')}}"></script>` on your `layouts.app` file.

**From [official document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport)**

> **In order to use the Passport Vue components, you must be using the Vue
> JavaScript framework**. These components also use the Bootstrap CSS
> framework. However, even if you are not using these tools, the
> components serve as a valuable reference for your own frontend
> implementation.

[Download vuejs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html+)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

In your dom, your components must have a parent with an id of "app" since you declared it in your app.js :

`const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});`

Comment: the #app is in my @extends('layouts.app'). I tried to render the example.vue in the same page it seems to be working..

Comment: Did you run `php artisan make:auth` command ?
In your layouts/app.blade.php, do you get this code :
`<script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>` ?

Comment: Yes to both the questions.

Comment: Like someone asks earlier, does browser console say anything ?